# HowTo extract MimeType from a byte[]

Tags: java, file, mime-types, magic-numbers

I've a web page that that can be used to upload files.
Now I need to check if the file type is correct (zip, jpg, pdf,...).
I can use the mimeType that comes with the request but I don't trust the user and let's say I want to be sure that nobody is able to upload a .gif file that was renamed in .jpg
I think that in this case I should inspect the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files).
[This](http://aperture.sourceforge.net/tutorial/mimetypes.html) is a java library I've found that seems to achieve what I need 'extract the mimetype from the magic number'.
Is this a correct solution or what do you suggest?

**UPDATE:**
I've found the [mime-util project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mime-util/) and it seems very good and up-to-date! (maybe better then Java Mime Magic Library?)
[Here is a list](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0487.html) of utility projects that can help you to extract mime-types

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try [Java Mime Magic Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/)

```
byte[] data = ...
MagicMatch match = Magic.getMagicMatch(data);
String mimeType = match.getMimeType();
```

Comment: It does not detect docx files correctly.. it keeps giving application/zip as mimetype...

Comment: @OscarPérez A docx is indeed a zip archive containing a bunch of XML files, so it's technically correct. You could inspect the archive yourself to see if it is a docx or similar. This would probably be out of scope for this small library.

Comment: @sfussenegger What can you say about this SO question [check file of MIME-type with JMimeMagic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15325047/check-file-of-mime-type-with-jmimemagic)?

Answer (score 10):

I'm sure the library posted by @sfussenegger is the best solution, but I do it by hand with the following snippet that I hope it could help you.

```
DESCONOCIDO("desconocido", new byte[][] {}), PDF("PDF",
            new byte[][] { { 0x25, 0x50, 0x44, 0x46 } }), JPG("JPG",
            new byte[][] { { (byte) 0xff, (byte) 0xd8, (byte) 0xff,
                    (byte) 0xe0 } }), RAR("RAR", new byte[][] { { 0x52,
            0x61, 0x72, 0x21 } }), GIF("GIF", new byte[][] { { 0x47, 0x49,
            0x46, 0x38 } }), PNG("PNG", new byte[][] { { (byte) 0x89, 0x50,
            0x4e, 0x47 } }), ZIP("ZIP", new byte[][] { { 0x50, 0x4b } }), TIFF(
            "TIFF", new byte[][] { { 0x49, 0x49 }, { 0x4D, 0x4D } }), BMP(
            "BMP", new byte[][] { { 0x42, 0x4d } });
```

Regards.

PD: The best of it is that it doesn't have any dependency.
PD2: No warranty about it's correctness!
PD3: "desconocido" stands for "unknown" (in spanish)

Answer (score -2):

The activation framework is [Sun's answer to this](http://72.5.124.55/javase/technologies/desktop/javabeans/jaf/downloads/index.html).  And you may well have this already in the classpath of your app server

Comment: I tried activation framework's getContentType() over some .pdf, .xls files but unfortunately the method is always returning 'application/octet-stream'. only for .txt is giving something like 'text/plain'

Comment: actually the getContentType only maps the file based on the file extension and a map of mimeType that you provide... this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: I agree, that's not what you're looking for!

Comment: Linking to an IP address is weird.