# how to get the real type/mime type in JAVA (like finfo\mime_content_type in PHP)?

Tags: java, php, file, mime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting A File’s Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java)

i am looking for some function / plugin that's doing what finfo\mime_content_type doing in php.
an exemple : 
[click here to see an image](http://lior-portal.co.il//images/MTM0OTg3NzI2Nmxpb3IucmFyLmpwZWc=.jpeg)

but if you will download the image to your computer and **open it like a *.rar* file** (with win rar or something else), you will see an rar dictonary , with a file named "garfild" !

in PHP , finfo or mime_content_type would decide that's not an image **(but other servises like GD functions , will find it like an image)** , and i am searching
some thing like this in JAVA.
thank you very much :) 
sorry for my newbie english , i'm not from eslish-speaking country :)

Comment: Java's not an acronym, btw :)

Comment: Have you looked at http://tika.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a library which is able to recognize a file's magic number, which is an indication for the actual file type. You could try jMimeMagic: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/ (as described in [HowTo extract MimeType from a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915317/howto-extract-mimetype-from-a-byte))