# Find File type unix

Tags: java, file, unix

How to find the type of the file? 
I am writing a code to find that file on unix system is image file or not?

Possibilities exists that someone has changed the extension.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915317/howto-extract-mimetype-from-a-byte

Comment: `ImageIO.read(..)` is a good way to test if a chunk of bytes represents an image (as understood by J2SE).

Comment: @Martin, unlikely, that's for a mime type, which is generally a file being downloaded. MIME types aren't usually stored alongside arbitrary files on UNIX filesystems.

Comment: Well, MIME types are one way to describe the type of a file that happens to be pretty standard. Ultimately that question is about using magic numbers at the beginning of a file to determine file type, which is really the only way to heuristically detect file type from raw file contents with no additional context.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `file` command:

```
file <name of file>
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 has `Files.probeContentType(Path path)` which probes the content type of a file. See API for details.