# Java validate image header

Tags: java, image, arrays

I am having one requirement where i need to identify the type of the image not by the files extension but by validating the header. I am trying to validate a JPEG file by magic number validation.

```
File imgFile =
   new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg");
byte[] ba = Files.toByteArray(imgFile); //Its a google guava library
int i = 0; 
if(ba [i] == 0xFF && ba[i+1] == 0xD8 && ba[i+2] == 0xFF && ba[i+3] == 0xE0){
   System.out.println("isJPEG");
}
```

But the condition is not getting satisfied at all. `ba[i]`  returns `-1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1915317/1055089

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java the `byte` primitive is signed and has a range from -128 to 127, which means your `ba[0]` comes out as `-1`, whereas `0xFF` is interpreted as an int as `255`. If you do a bitwise AND with `0xFF` using the `&` operator this converts the signed byte to the correct value and your code will work, as follows:

```
    File imgFile =
           new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg");
        byte[] ba = Files.toByteArray(imgFile); //Its a google guava library
        int i = 0; 
        if((ba [i] & 0xFF) == 0xFF && (ba[i+1] & 0xFF) == 0xD8 && (ba[i+2] & 0xFF) == 0xFF 
           && (ba[i+3] & 0xFF) == 0xE0) {
           System.out.println("isJPEG");
        }
```

I'm not sure about the exact logic you are using however, as wikipedia states that the magic numbers for JPEGs are as follows:

> JPEG image files begin with FF D8 and end with FF D9

`FF E0` is JFIF specific, so you may want to double check why you are checking for this

The following would be the code to use to make the checks as per Wikipedia:

```
        File imgFile =                 
                    new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\Chrysanthemum.jpg");
        byte[] ba = Files.toByteArray(imgFile); //Its a google guava library
        int i = 0; 
        if((ba [i] & 0xFF) == 0xFF && (ba[i+1] & 0xFF) == 0xD8 && (ba[ba.length - 2] & 0xFF) == 0xFF 
           && (ba[ba.length - 1] & 0xFF) == 0xD9) {
           System.out.println("isJPEG");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you.It worked. I guess i need to look more into ditwise operations.

Comment: You're welcome. All primitive numeric data types in Java are signed and represented in Two's complement notation, see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement. You will notice that the unsigned 255 is -1 when represented in Two's complement