# How to find the mime type of a content file in python without using Magic library?

Tags: python, django, mime-types, jython

Is there some way to determine the MIME type of a file by it's content without using Magic Library in **Python/Django**?

I'm getting the content from a HTTP POST and I need to get the mime-type.

I cannot trust the content-type:

```
request.FILES[request.POST['fileToUpload']].content_type
```

It can be changed easily by changing the file extension.

```
document = request.FILES[request.POST['fileToUpload']].read()
```

I would need to get the content-type of the document:

THX

Comment: Why don't you want to use a wrapper around [`libmagic`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic/)? It is exactly its purpose as far as I can tell...

Comment: If you're looking for something built-in to Python, the only similar module is [`imghdr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/imghdr.html), but that only works for images. If you don't want to use `libmagic` then you'll either have to find an alternative third-party library, or write your own from scratch.

Comment: libmagic module uses ctypes and I'm using Jython and I cannot use Ctypes.

Comment: @marmar If you're using Jython, then you can use a Java-based library. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1915317/howto-extract-mimetype-from-a-byte).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `subprocess` module to execute `/usr/bin/file`, if you are on a Unix or Linux system (and possibly on Windows per [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/272338/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-linux-file-command-for-windows)), and have exec privileges.  The `subprocess` module is supported by Jython, and documentation is available at http://www.jython.org/docs/library/subprocess.html.

Answer (score -1):

May be not perfect but can do what you need

```
file_type = request.FILES[request.POST['fileToUpload']].content_type.split('/')[0]
```

Comment: I want to know the content type by checking the file content