# How to detect corrupted files on java server side?

Tags: java, file-upload

I know in order to check corrupted files, we can read entire file too see if there's exception for corrupted files. However, that doesn't check for valid/invalid format, it will succeed even with a corrupted pdf. so corresponding to each format, we have to use standard library (i.e. pdf library) to read entire file which is kinda tedious.  I am wondering if there is better solution Or are there any packages/Services that we can validate multiple types, so we don't need a separate api for each one.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1915344/416300) suggests using [Java Mime Magic Library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmimemagic/)

Comment: @summerbulb this isn't only detect mimetype, but also detect corrupted files.

Comment: The mimetype is determined using the file data and so will let you know if the _format_ is corrupted. Are you interested in validating the file's integrity or are you scared of malicious files?

Comment: @summerbulb  I scared when I downloaded user's uploaded files on s3, I am unable to open it.  so I want to not accept this kind of files.